# Zeros of derivatives of Dirichlet Eta function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Let 
$$
\eta^{(d)}(z) = 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\dfrac
{(-1)^d(-1)^{n-1}\ln(n)^d}
{n^z}
$$
be the derivative of Dirichlet Eta function of order $d$.

Does it exist any known or not known zero of $\eta^{(d)}(z)$ such that $d \geq 1$ and $\frac{1}{2}<\Re(z)<1$

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer, but relevant: Bohr and Landau showed in [1] that if a Dirichlet series converges for $\sigma>0$,
then $N(\alpha,T)$, the number of zeros for $\sigma>\alpha$ and $0<t<T$, is $O(T)$ for $\alpha>1/2$.

---

Update ($d=1$ case):  The *Mathematica* command

FindRoot[2^(1 - s) Log[2] Zeta[s] + (1 - 2^(1 - s)) Zeta'[s], {s,1. + 95. I}]

returns 
{s -> 0.926336 + 95.3143 I}

[1] Ein Satz über Dirichletsche Reihen mit Anwendung auf die
$\zeta$ Funktion und die $L$-Funktionen, Rend. Circ. Mat. Palermo 37 (1914), 269-272.

Comment: Thanks @Stopple for your suggestion, so we don't know if $\eta^{(d)}(z)=0$ when $d \geq 1$ and $\frac{1}{2} < \Re(z) < 1$ ?

Comment: thanks @Stopple for your example